# How to verify if given user@host with 'password' exists in MySQL 8.0+?

Tags: mysql, authentication, password, mysql-8.0

I write sanity check script for an application. One of the tests is supposed to verify that a given user@host with 'password' exists in MySQL. I'm using simple native hash passwords. In MySQL5.7- there is the `PASSWORD()` function that allows me to query `mysql.user` and verify that the user exists and the passwords match. Is there a way to accomplish this in MySQL8.0+? Documentation page for `PASSWORD()` in MySQL 5.7 does not provide any alternatives and the function is removed in MySQL 8.0.

I could simply try to add the user again, but I feel my script should know and register an event of missing user with expected credentials.

Please note that I do not necessarily need to generate password hash, I just want to verify that given user/password exists. This needs to be automated so solutions like 'try to log in with **user/password** from **host** machine' do not count as I may not have access to the **host** machine

Comment: Look in `mysql`.`user`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is an alternative that MySQL (really Oracle) does not mention.

- Back on `Apr 22, 2015`, I posted the [Algorithm for the Password Function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98529/why-are-mysql-password-hashes-internally-saved-with-a-star-asterisk/98558#98558)
- MySQL 8.0 will still store the PASSWORD function output in the authentication_string column if you create the user using the mysql_native_password plugin.

Here is the algorithm

```
SET @plaintextpassword = 'whatever password you want';
SELECT CONCAT('*',UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(@plaintextpassword)))));
```

## GIVING CREDIT

I first learned this from a blog by a company called PalominoDB. They changed their name to blackbird. Pythian purchased blackbird. Pythian now has it as a blog post with this algorithm : [Hashing Algorithm in MySQL PASSWORD()](http://www.pythian.com/blog/hashing-algorithm-in-mysql-password-2/)